# REST API 'between' parameters

Tags: api, rest

I'm trying to make an external REST API call to rest.php.  I was getting "Unable to decode supplied JSON", but then I figured out I could take the values I was stuffing into json (from the API Explorer) and then make them their own parameters ([REST API without JSON just key=value](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4974/rest-api-without-json-just-key-value)).

I'm trying to request contributions between two dates.  In the json style as shown in the API Explorer, it's like this:

```
&json={"receive_date":{"BETWEEN":["2017-12-01","2017-12-01"]}}
```

I'm trying this, and it's not working:

```
&received_date[BETWEEN]=2017-12-01,2017-12-02
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just figured it out:

```
&received_date[BETWEEN][]=2017-12-01&received_date[BETWEEN][]=2017-12-02
```

Comment: Great, you can mark your answer as best answer.

Comment: Your answer helped me generalize this to other OR searches, for instance (using REST format, v3 API) &last_name[]=name1&last_name[]=name2 Thx!